# Sql Query to determine when log shipping last took place

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I need a SQL query to determine when log shipping last occured for a given database. Would this be correct?

```
SELECT  Max(restore_date)
FROM    msdb.dbo.restorehistory 
WHERE   destination_database_name = 'XXXXXXXXXX' AND
        restore_type = 'L'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

**but**

only if you do not restored logs manually last time.

**and**

better use the procedures at *Monitor Instance* dedicated to [this task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186223.aspx)